# Background Image for Panorama Control in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-image, panorama-control

I have five sections in Panorama. The background Image I am using is 618x340. Can I set the Image from the last section that is Fifth section. Usually it starts the BG Image from the first section. How do I do this?

Comment: If I add section wise Background Image will it move like the whole panorama control Background Image?At Least will it mimic the same?

Comment: Is there any size for panorama BG Image? And I have a white color Image in PNG format, It changes to black in dark theme and I don't want it to change. How should i handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default panorama item as 5th that time your background image will start from 5 items, however this item will become your screen's first item to display. you can set it in your .CS file onload event.

```
myPanorama.DefaultItem = myPanorama.Items[4];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, item 5 has to be item 5 itself. I am doing only to adjust the image.

Comment: Then you have to designed image as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This will need some minor Photoshop skills.

Crop the first section of your image and place it towards the end of the image.

Suppose your original image is as shown below.

```
+------|------|------|------|------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|   I  | II   | III  | IV   |   V  |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------|------|------|------|------+
```

The image somehow makes it look quite obvious.

```
+------|------|------|------|------+
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|   V  | II   | III  | IV   |   I  |
|      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |
+------|------|------|------|------+
```